# How to open store of windows phone when clicking the button in wp8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

i have developing an app in windows phone 8 visual studio 2012 and xaml

i have a requirement to open a windows store from my app button click

please tell me how to open windows phone store from my app

Comment: You wanna go to store hub? or your app in store?

Comment: what you meant by store hub?

Comment: My answer shows how to open windows phone store,please read it.Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open Windows Phone Store, You can use MarketplaceHubTask like this:

add namespace:

```
using namespace Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```

and the C# code:

```
MarketplaceHubTask task = new MarketplaceHubTask();
task.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

`MarketPlaceDetailTask` is documented as able to go to the current application's page in the windows phone store. If you wanted to navigate to a paricular app's page try this out. 
Or else if you want to naviagate to the windows phone store use the `WebBrowserTask`.

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = 
    new MarketplaceDetailTask
    {
        //give the app id as your ContentIdentifier
        ContentIdentifier = null,
        ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications
    };

marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: sorry i am new to wp8 please tell me how to find ContentIdentifier

Comment: @KarthikManoharan you can find the ContentIdentifier from your Dev account...Go to your App details there you'll find a component called App ID. That's the unique ID to your particular app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("www.windowsphone.com/store");
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

Comment: But i need to open phones app store

Comment: did you try this code? I have redirected to the app store itself, see my url. It should work I think. I don't have a phone with me now else would have tested myself.